# С# найти максимальный элемент и сумму нечетных элементов после него

Tags: c#, массивы

```
namespace ConsoleApplication20
   { class Program
    {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Введите количество элементов в массиве a:");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[,] a = new int[n, m];
        int s = 0; 
          double max = a[0, 0];
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                a[i, j] = random.Next(-100, 100);
                if (max < a[i, j])
                {  max = a[i, j]; }
                else  { s += a[i, j];}
                Console.Write("{0,4}", a[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("max = {0}", max);
        Console.WriteLine("sum = {0}", s);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
   }}}
```

Comment: где и какая ошибка?

Comment: @zxxrc19 абсолютно непонятно, чем мы вам помочь можем. Вы назвали свой вопрос, выдали кусок кода. Без комментария хотя бы "Где ошибка, не работает" и подобное. Просто кусок кода

Answer (score 3):

Хех, чисто ради любопытства попробовал сделать по своему. Критерий было несколько компактность, без array (ненавижу их) и с Linq. В итоге получил что то вроде этого:

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите количество элементов в массиве:");
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var items);
int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var count);

var total = items * count;
var numbers = new List<int>();
var rnd = new Random();

for (var index = 0; index < total; index++)
    numbers.Add(rnd.Next(-100, 100));

var max = numbers.Max();
var maxIndex = numbers.FindIndex(x => x == max);
var sumOdd = numbers.Skip(maxIndex + 1).Where(x => x % 2 != 0).Sum();

int current = 0;
var result = numbers.GroupBy(_ => current++ % items).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();

Console.WriteLine("Результат:");
result.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", x)));
Console.WriteLine($"Максимальное: {max}");
Console.WriteLine($"Сумма: {sumOdd}");

Console.ReadKey();
```

Поясню:

- `int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var items);` - Изначально тут мы получим ошибку если пользователь напишет не число, либо вовсе Null. Тут два варианта, либо обрабатывать это, либо использовать `TryParse()` который отдает `bool` и через `out` мы можем получить наше `int` значение.
- `var total = items * count;` - Сама суть всего этого "шаманства" в том, что мы изначально создаем простую коллекцию случайных чисел и потом ее разбиваем на нужные нам части. Вот чтобы не ошибиться потом в разбитие нам стоит для начала посчитать сколько всего чисел должно быть в коллекции.
- `for (var index = 0; index < total; index++)` - Тут самая простая генерация чисел.
- `var max = numbers.Max();` - Получаем самое большое число.
- `var maxIndex = numbers.FindIndex(x => x == max);` - Так, как нам в дальнейшем надо отсечь все до `max`, то нужно узнать индекс этого числа.
- `var sumOdd = numbers.Skip(maxIndex + 1).Where(x => x % 2 != 0).Sum();` - Пропускаем все до `max` (включая его самого), берем все нечетный числа и складываем.
- `var result = numbers.GroupBy(_ => current++ % items).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();` - Разбиваем коллекцию на необходимые части. По сути все просто, группируем на нужное кол-во элементов, далее для удобства делаем из этого `List<List<int>>`.

Ну вроде все, выводим это и смотрим результат:

```
Введите количество элементов в массиве:
5
5
Результат:
-21 -47 8 36 78
18 83 7 29 40
-54 -51 -95 -54 6
-74 -48 69 52 -30
-55 -48 72 -30 83
Максимальное: 83
Сумма: 42
```

Опять же повторюсь, тут мне чисто стало интересно решить эту задачу иначе, чисто эксперимент. Так что как ответ это вряд ли (ибо вопрос все же как заставить работать код из вопроса), но для развития..., думаю можно почерпнуть немого полезностей.

Comment: Можно SkipWhile вместо FindIndex+Skip

Comment: @АндрейNOP Как вариант, да, но тоже возьмет само Max число и его придется пропускать, добавив скорей всего еще и Skip(). Но от FindIndex точно избавит :-)

Comment: Не возьмет, просто надо написать правильное условие, что-то вроде: `.SkipWhile(x => x <= max)` :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP тогда в таком случае условие будет вечно true и мы все пропустим, ибо у нас только одно максимальное значение (пример: 1 2 **3** 2 1) которое мы пропускаем из за `=` и дальше числа у нас также попадают под `<`. Так что я даже без понятия какое тут условие грамотно подойдет...

Comment: @АндрейNOP Так проверил. Получаю 0 элементов. В каком случае условие станет ложным? Под `<=` попадают все элементы ведь.

Comment: Ах, ну да, вы правы. Придется писать строго меньше и потом делать еще один `Skip(1)`. Хотя, на один проход все равно меньше получаем. Но в любом случае, классическим циклом можно вообще всё за один проход сделать. Так что — да, большой роли здесь не сыграет, а асимптоматика всё равно та же (n)

Answer (score 1):

Вы считаете все числа подряд без разбора на четные и нет. Так же, при определения нового максимума вы не сбрасываете ваш счетчик:

```
if (max < a[i, j])
{ 
    max = a[i, j];
    s = 0;
}
else if (a[i, j] % 2 != 0) 
{ 
    s += a[i, j]; 
}
```

---

Так как у вас массив целочисленных значений, следовательно и максимум будет целочисленным: `int max = a[0, 0];`

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace tstCons
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите количество элементов в массиве a:");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int[,] a = new int[n, m];
            int s = 0;
            int max = -100; // присваеваем минимальное возможноме значение
            int maxI = 0, maxJ = 0; // чтобы запомнить координату максимального элемента
            Random random = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    a[i, j] = random.Next(-100, 100);
                    if (max < a[i, j])
                    {
                        max = a[i, j];
                        maxI = i;
                        maxJ = j;
                    } // ищем максимум и запоминаем его координаты
                    Console.Write(a[i, j].ToString() + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            bool flag = false; //исключим максимальный элемент
            for (int i = maxI; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = maxJ; j < m; j++)
                {
                    if (!flag) // если элемент - максимум, то ничего не делаем
                    {
                        flag = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (a[i,j]%2 != 0) s += a[i, j]; // проверяем элемент на четность и увеличеваем счетчик
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("max = {0}", max);
            Console.WriteLine("sum = {0}", s);
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```